# Updated way to destroy a controller using the as and this syntax

Tags: angularjs, garbage-collection

When using the 'as' syntax and binding values on the controller is there a new way to destroy the controller or should I still be using the scope?

If I declare a controller in the dom using the 'as' syntax:

```
<section ng-controller="MyController as mine">...
```

And you use the 'this' syntax to bind things to the controller instead of the scope, how do you make sure the controller is destroyed?

```
myApp.controller('MyApp', ['pubsub', function (pubsub) {
  var myController = this;
  this.subject = ""
  this.myTopic = pubsub.subscribe('mytopic', function(data) {
    myController.subject = data; 
  }
}
```

This would create a memory leak, my controller would not get cleaned up because the pubsub is holding a reference to my controller.

Is there a way to create a destroy function for my controller, or do I still us the scope object to listen to the destroy event?

```
myApp.controller('MyApp', ['pubsub', '$scope', function (pubsub, $scope) {
...
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
  if (myController.myTopic) {
      myController.myTopic.unsubcribe();
      myController.myTopic = null;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$scope` to do something special, such as listen for events, broadcasting, watching, emitting, etc, is perfectly fine, even when using `controllerAs` syntax.

Comment: So is there an alternative way to do this in `controllerAs` syntax without `$scope` ?